# How to use aggregate with $near mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was trying to get random 20 foods near the particular location. When i used find it works but how to use aggregate with $near
**Schema:**

```
const foodSchema = new Schema({
      foodName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      price: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      shopName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      isVerified:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false,
        required:true
      },
      isEnabled:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false,
        required:true
      }
      ,
      location: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: [],
        
       },
      shopId:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Shop',
        required: true
      }
      
    });
    
    foodSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });
```

```
Food.aggregate([{$match:{isEnabled:true,location: {
        $near: {
         $maxDistance: 10000,
         $geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [13.3339, 80.1943]
         }
        }
       }}}])
      .then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        res.render('user/home',{
          pageTitle:"UiMart",
          foodlist:data
        });
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.send("err");
      });
```

MongoError: $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context
How to use aggregate function with $near mongoose to get random foods near the particular location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this:

```
Food.aggregate
([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [13.3339, 80.1943] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: 10000,
        query: { "isEnabled": true }
     }
   }
])
```

In the aggregation framework the `$geoNear` should be the first in the pipeline and you can use the `query` to filter the results instead of using `match`.